# Asyn task's onProgressUpdate method is not being called one to one

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using Asyn Task to do some work in the background and then i am updating the UI using onProgressUpdate().The problem is that it is not being called one to one,means if i call it at this moment itself before the execution of the very next line of code,sometimes it is getting called and completes its work,but sometimes it completes its work after some delay.`I want to know that can we make it sure that the onProgressUpdate() must execute when we want it` to or it depends on the cpu of the device as when to execute the onProgressUpdate(),instantly or after some delay.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: Sorry sir,but the answer of my question is not given there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `onProgressUpdate()`, in reality you are posting a request to an handler to have a peace of code run in another Thread.

It's up to Android OS to decide when is the best timming to switch threads, and only then you code will run.

You can somehow force a `Thread` switch, by requesting current thread to pause. Ex:

```
 Thread.sleep(1);
```

However, you can't be sure that the next thread running will be the UI thread, where `onProgressUpdate()` will be run.

Regards.

Comment: It means that there is no way to accompolish onProgressUpdate() in the way i want to.Its sad.

Comment: There is, but it's not that simple. You will need to use a `sinchronized` block around a shared object, and make your AsynkTask to `wait()` on that object until `onProgressUpdate()` finishes and call `notify()`. Not correctly used, this leades to dead-locks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call publishProgress from within doInBackground manually.

From Android Document,

doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. ... This step can also use publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress. These values are published on the UI thread, in the onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.

Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I am doing it in the same way but not getting the desired functionality from onProgressUpdate()